# Link from label to ref and back?

Tags: links

I would like that the objects marked with label clickable so that when you click on it moves you to the relative `\ref` object and the other way around.

How should I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item test\label{l1}
\end{enumerate}


   \pagebreak

   test2\ref{l1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DG' If I apply that to the MWE above I still don't get clickable links. And it is also incompatible with hyperref.

Comment: @DG' That does never happen in my case, each ref points to a different label.

Comment: maybe it was a too minimal example. Actually the labels are always attached to items, so with hyperref the link from ref->label is already there. I want the other way too (label->ref)

Comment: @DG' I've asked the question because I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: @Mico As I said it is not the case that there is more than one `\ref` per `\label`. I cannot rely on the pdf viewer because this will be used with many different viewers, it's not for personal use.

Comment: @Mico by the way, is it really this difficult to achieve? I thought it was a matter of using some hyperref option or a specific package. Had no idea this was an "hard" problem.

Comment: @mico So how do you set up the two-way jump between refs and labels given that I don't have multiple refs per label? Could you give an example? It will not be confusing because each ref is an answer and each label is a question. So if the reader found himself on the answers page, he will know that clicking the answer will bring him to the relative question and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your setup to be as follows: You have numbered answers in one part of the document, you have answers somewhere else in the document, and you would like to provide two-way hyperlinks between Question 1 and Answer to Question 1, Question 2 and Answer to Question 2, etc.

- If you have numbered questions and increment the question-related counter using `\refstepcounter`, you can use `\ref` in the answer to create a link to the numbered question. If `hyperref` is loaded, the `\ref` will be resolved into a hyperlink automatically. The only tricky part is to create a hyperlink from the question to the answer; you can't use `\ref` as in all likelihood there's no (independent) counter associated with the answers. Fortunately, `hyperref` provides the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` pair of macros for just this case.
- In the example below, I've set up an environment called `question` that takes *three* arguments: The question's title, the text of the `\label` that's associated with the question, and the name of the hypertarget associated with the answer. The third argument is used in the environment's `\hyperlink` instruction.
- The corresponding `answer` entry takes *two* arguments: the argument of the `\label` macro of the associated question, and the name of the answer's hypertarget. (Note that arguments 2 and 3 of the question should be the same as the arguments 1 and 2 of the associated answer.) The second argument is used in the environment's `\hypertarget` instruction.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \Box macro
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=red]
           {hyperref}
\usepackage[textheight=3cm]
           {geometry} %% just for this example

\newcounter{quest}
\newenvironment{question}[3]{%
   \refstepcounter{quest} \label{#2}
   \par\bigskip\noindent
   \textbf{Question \thequest: #1?}
   \par\medskip

   For an answer, click here: \hyperlink{#3}{$\Box$}}{\par\bigskip}

\newenvironment{answer}[2]{%
   \par\bigskip\noindent%
   \hypertarget{#2}{\textbf{Answer to Question \ref{#1}}}%
   \par\medskip}{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{What's the meaning of life}%
                {quest:life}{ans:life}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{What is Pythagoras' Theorem}%
                {quest:pyth}{ans:pyth}
\end{question}

\newpage
\begin{answer}{quest:life}{ans:life}
Mumble, mumble, mumble \dots
\end{answer}

\begin{answer}{quest:pyth}{ans:pyth}
Mumble, mumble, mumble \dots
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use multiple `\ref`s per `\label` you could use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{#2}\label{back:#1}
}
\newcommand{\myref}[2]{%
  \hyperref[back:#1]{#2}\label{#1}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \mylabel{l1}{test}
  \end{enumerate}

  \pagebreak

  \myref{l1}{test2}
\end{document}
```

Another solution would be to pack `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` in a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{%
  \hyperlink{back:#1}{\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}
}
\newcommand{\myref}[2]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\hypertarget{back:#1}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \mylabel{l1}{test}
  \end{enumerate}

  \pagebreak

  \myref{l1}{test2}
\end{document}
```