# Hide content to show later

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, exercises

My question appeared about this [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210564/15256).

I have a list of exercise-answers but I don't want to show the answers immediately but after till I'll pull with a command and fetch all the answers till there.

By example:

```
\hidesolutions
\begin{exercise} this is an exercise.1 \end{exercise}
\begin{solution}  this is a solution for the above exercise.1  \end{solution}

\begin{exercise} this is an exercise.2 \end{exercise}
\begin{solution}  this is a solution for the above exercise.2  \end{solution}
\stophidesolutions

\begin{exercise} this is an exercise.3 \end{exercise}
\begin{solution}  this is a solution for the above exercise.3  \end{solution}

\hidesolutions
\begin{exercise} this is an exercise.4 \end{exercise}
\begin{solution}  this is a solution for the above exercise.4  \end{solution}

\begin{exercise} this is an exercise.5 \end{exercise}
\begin{solution}  this is a solution for the above exercise.5  \end{solution}
\stophidesolutions

\section{solutions}
\showsolutions 
\showsolutions
```

Results it should be:

1. show exercises 1 and 2
2. show exercise 3 and his answer
3. show exercises 4 and 5
4. show a new section `solutions`
5. show answers 1 and 2
6. show answers 4 and 5

Comment: I have added support for hyperlinks

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222814

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\theoremstyle{definition} % body text is upright
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newtheorem*{innersolution}{Solution ~ of ~ \dvvv_exercise_ref:}

\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq { {\theexercise}{\exp_not:V \BODY} }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution*}{}
 {
  \cs_set:Npx \dvvv_exercise_ref: { \theexercise }
  \innersolution
 }
 {
  \endinnersolution
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printsolutions}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    \dvvv_print_solutions:nn ##1
   }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
 }

\seq_new:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dvvv_print_solutions:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \dvvv_exercise_ref: { #1 }
  \begin{innersolution} #2 \end{innersolution}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}

Some optional text in between.

\begin{solution*}
This is a solution.
\end{solution*}

The solution has been printed immediately, because
\texttt{solution*} has been used.

\begin{exercise}
This is another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is yet another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
Too much.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

The solutions are stored in a FIFO list; using `solution*` makes the solution print at the spot.

[image]

Here's the same, but with support for hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition} % body text is upright
\newtheorem{innerexercise}{Exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{}
 {
  \innerexercise\label{dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label}
 }
 {
  \endinnerexercise
 }
\newtheorem*{innersolution}{\dvvv_exercise_ref:}

\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    {\theinnerexercise}{\exp_not:V \BODY}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution*}{}
 {
  \cs_set:Npx \dvvv_exercise_ref:
   {
    \exp_not:N \hyperref
     [
      dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label
     ]
     {
      Solution~of~\exp_not:N\ref*{dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label}
     }
   }
  \innersolution
 }
 {
  \endinnersolution
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printsolutions}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    \dvvv_print_solutions:nn ##1
   }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
 }

\seq_new:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dvvv_print_solutions:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \dvvv_exercise_ref:
   {
    \hyperref[dvvv_#1_label]{Solution~of~\ref*{dvvv_#1_label}}
   }
  \begin{innersolution} #2 \end{innersolution}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}

Some optional text in between.

\begin{solution*}
This is a solution.
\end{solution*}

The solution has been printed immediately, because
\texttt{solution*} has been used.

\begin{exercise}
This is another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is yet another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
Too much.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's look at the first solution step by step. The second just adds setting automatically a label for each `exercise` environment, to be used for the hyperlink, so it's not much more complicated.

#### Step 1

Define an `exercise` environment; this is standard

#### Step 2

Define an `innersolution` environment as an unnumbered theorem; the label text depends on the value of `\dvvv_exercise_ref:` that will be set at printing time

#### Step 3

Define a `solution` environment, with the help of `\NewEnviron`, that makes LaTeX store the environment's content in the macro `\BODY`. The value of the macro, together with the current exercise number, is stored in a sequence.

#### Step 4

The `solution*` environment just sets the value of `\dvvv_exercise_ref:` to the current exercise number and calls `innersolution`

#### Step 5

Define the `\printsolutions` command, which simply maps the sequence, that is, delivers to `\dvvv_print_solutions:nn` each of its item. Finally it clears the sequence.

#### Step 6

The `\dvvv_print_solutions:nn` function uses the fact that the solutions were stored in the format `{<number>}{<contents>}`, so it uses the first argument for setting the value of `\dvvv_exercise_ref:` and feeds the second argument to the `innersolution` environment.

### Links also in the reverse direction (from exercise to solution)

The trick is to add another label at solutions and a hyperlink at the exercise.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}% name
  {\topsep}%     Space above
  {\topsep}%     Space below
  {\normalfont}% Body font
  {}%            Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}%   Thm head font
  {.}%           Punctuation after thm head
  { }%           Space after thm head
  {\hyperref[dvvv_#2_reverse_label]{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}}% Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{exercise} % body text is upright
\newtheorem{innerexercise}{Exercise}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{}
 {
  \innerexercise\label{dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label}
 }
 {
  \endinnerexercise
 }
\newtheorem*{innersolution}{\dvvv_exercise_ref:}

\NewEnviron{solution}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    {\theinnerexercise}{\exp_not:V \BODY}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution*}{}
 {
  \phantomsection\label{dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _reverse_label}
  \cs_set:Npx \dvvv_exercise_ref:
   {
    \exp_not:N \hyperref
     [
      dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label
     ]
     {
      Solution~of~\exp_not:N\ref*{dvvv_ \theinnerexercise _label}
     }
   }
  \innersolution
 }
 {
  \endinnersolution
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printsolutions}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    \dvvv_print_solutions:nn ##1
   }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
 }

\seq_new:N \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dvvv_print_solutions:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \dvvv_exercise_ref:
   {
    \phantomsection\label{dvvv_#1_reverse_label}
    \hyperref[dvvv_#1_label]{Solution~of~\ref*{dvvv_#1_label}}
   }
  \begin{innersolution} #2 \end{innersolution}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}

Some optional text in between.

\begin{solution*}
This is a solution.
\end{solution*}

The solution has been printed immediately, because
\texttt{solution*} has been used.

\begin{exercise}
This is another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
A solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
This is yet another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
Too much.
\end{solution}

\clearpage
\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

### UPDATE March 2019

With `xparse` released 2019-03-05 or later, there's no need for `environ` any longer. Replace the code for `solution` by

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_dvvv_solution_group_seq
   {
    {\theinnerexercise}{ \exp_not:n { #1 } }
   }
 }
 {}
```

Comment: I should confess that I like the result by I need to learn more latex, your code looks so cryptic to me. Thanks a lot, btw.

Comment: @d555 I added some explanations and also improved the hyperlink support, making all of “Solution of X” into a hyperlink.

Comment: How could one modify this example so that the exercise is linked to the solution (the same way the solution is linked to the corresponding exercise)?

Comment: @MathieuVienney Good question. I'll try later.

Comment: @egreg, thanks. I obviously found how to add a label to the solutions, but the real difficulty for me is to add an hyperref in the title of the exercise environment.

Comment: @MathieuVienney That requires defining a new theorem style. Good exercise for me. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg. Your solution works just fine when you have a quite simple solution. But if I want to include for example a `lstlisting`, it doesn't work anymore. Do you think of an easy way of doing that ? Moreover, I noticed I can use a `tcblisting` inside `exercise`, but not inside `solution`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be done with `tcolorbox`. This package provides commands `\tcbstartrecording[file]`, `\tcbstoprecording` and `\tcbinputrecording[file]` which can serve as OP's `\hidesolutions` and `\stophidesolutions`.

Any `tcolorbox` is divided into upper and lower parts. We can use the upper part as exercise and lower part as solution. Options `savelowerto` creates ans auxiliary file where lower part is saved. This file can be saved for later use with `record` option. And these recorded fragments can be included in our document with `\tcbinputrecording`.

Next code shows an example based on codes taken from "7.3 Example: Exercises" and "13.9 Creation of LaTeX exercices" in `tcolorbox` documentation.

I've also included `tcblisting` boxes in my questions and solutions because it was written as answer to  [NewEnviron, \BODY and lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257218/newenviron-body-and-lstlisting?lq=1) which has been closed before I could post it. I think is also valid for this question.

Code contains some comments which I hope will serve to understand how it works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
        enhanced, colframe=green!20!black, colback=yellow!10!white, 
        coltitle=green!40!black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Exercise~\thetcbcounter:},
        label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
        attach title to upper=\quad,
        after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
             {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution@\thetcbcounter}}},
        lowerbox=ignored,
        savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
        record={\string\solution{\thetcbcounter}%
               {solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
        #1}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
        enhanced, colframe=red!20!black, colback=yellow!10!white,             
        coltitle=red!40!black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise@#1} on page~\pageref{exercise@#1}:},
        phantomlabel={solution@#1},
        attach title to upper=\par,
        }{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{listing only}

\begin{document}
\section{Some problems}

% We start to record all `tcblower` parts in file `file1` for later provessing 
\tcbstartrecording[file1]

%Every exercise box contains an upper part which is processed and
%printed and a lower (solution) which printing is delayed.
%
\begin{exercise}
Type some nice code
\begin{mylisting}
This is my
first listing
\end{mylisting}
\tcblower       %<--------- Here upper part finishes and lower starts
The solution could be:
\begin{mylisting}
This is the solution
for the first listing problem
\end{mylisting}
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording  %<---- recording solutions in `file1` is finished. 

% Recording mechanism has been stopped. Solutions are printed after
% upper part. 
\begin{exercise}[lowerbox=visible]  %<--- lowerbox is `invisible` in `exercise` boxes
Type some nice code
\tcblower
The solution could be:
\begin{mylisting}
My code 2
\end{mylisting}
\end{exercise}

% another file will continue recording solutions
\tcbstartrecording[file2]

\begin{exercise}
Type some nice code
\tcblower
The solution could be:
\begin{mylisting}
My code 3
\end{mylisting}
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording

\section{Some solutions to previous problems}

%previous recorded files with solutions are processed and printed
\tcbinputrecords[file1]
\tcbinputrecords[file2]

\end{document}
```

Previous code is just an starting point. Some details, like references or style for not recorded solutions, must be solved. In any case, the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I really like the footer for each exercise as well as the header on the solutions. Thanks for sharing.