# How to automatically link questions and solutions with the Exsheets package?

Tags: cross-referencing, exsheets

I'm writing up some lecture notes that contain questions/problems for the reader scattered accross the text. The solutions are provided in the end of each chapter. [Exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) appears to be a nice package for doing so.

Students will use the document mainly electronically and so I'd like to hyperlink each question to the corresponding answer and vice-versa. Now [exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) has the option to `auto-label` each question with `\label{qu:id}` and the `id` is generated automatically as well. So far so good.

Using the `headings`, `solution/pre-hook` or `solution/post-hook` options I tried referencing the corresponding label, but don't manage to construct it. I tried using `\CurrentQuestionID` which, however, is empty when in the solution environment.

Any ideas how to accomplish the cross-linking automatically? Thanks!

Comment: This is a missing feature I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

With version 0.19 (2015/07/04) the hack isn't necessary anymore. The following preamble to the code below suffices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}[2015/07/04]

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myblock}{default}{
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  } ,
  title-post-code = \bfseries\space
    to question \GetQuestionProperty{ref}{\CurrentQuestionID}
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

The problem your having is (I guess) that when the solutions are printed `\CurrentQuestionID` doesn't hold the corresponding ID but in fact expands to an empty token list. This is probably a missing feature or even some kind of bug since arguably `\CurrentQuestionID` should work in for the solutions as well...

Here is a suggestion which will probably find its way into `exsheets` in the next few days:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myblock}{default}{
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  } ,
  title-post-code = \bfseries\space
    to question \GetQuestionProperty{ref}{\CurrentQuestionID}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__exsheets_print_solution:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \CurrentQuestionID {#3} % <<< this is needed
    \tl_use:N \l__exsheets_solutions_pre_hook_tl
    \exsheets_solutions_print_name:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
    \tl_use:N \l__exsheets_solutions_pre_body_hook_tl
    \use:n {#4}
    \tl_use:N \l__exsheets_solutions_post_body_hook_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__exsheets_solutions_post_hook_tl
    \exsheets_h_or_vspace:N \l__exsheets_solutions_skip_below_dim
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}
\begin{question}
  foo bar baz
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  blah blah
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
  foo bar baz
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  blah blah
\end{solution}

\section{Answers}
\SetupExSheets{headings=myblock}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In the direction solution->question this does exactly what I was looking for. Ideally, I'd like to place a link to the solution somewhere in the question as well (e.g. in the heading or post-hook). But the solutions are not auto-labelled, are they?

Comment: That's true, there isn't. There are reasons for this: since it it possible for a solution to be printed more than once this could result in multiple labels; also solutions don't have a counter that gets stepped so there is nothing to refer to other than the page.

Comment: That being said it should be possible with the fix in my answer and the question and solution hooks to build something.

Comment: @lukasimir I updated the answer

Comment: @clemens How can I add  links from all Exercises to solutions and reverse?