# exsheets: Link Solutions back to Questions

Tags: hyperref, exsheets

Using `exsheets`, I'd like to link questions to their solutions and solutions back to their questions. This issue is also discussed in the question [How to automatically links questions and solutions with the Exsheets package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222814/how-to-automatically-links-questions-and-solutions-with-the-exsheets-package), although the accepted answer only solves half the problem (namely, the solution-->question linkage).

I've tried to use `solution/pre-body-hook=\label{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}` to label the solutions, then insert links to them using `question/pre-body-hook`. (This approach was suggested as a possible approach in the question I linked above).

My issue is that none of the solution labels seem to be pointing to the right place. Namely, they all point to the solutions section, rather than to the individual solution. See full code below. (Note: version 0.19 of `exsheets` is required.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets} %Requires version 0.19
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetupExSheets{
    question/pre-body-hook = {%
        \hyperref[sol:\CurrentQuestionID]{Link to Solution}%
        \dots ref value is \ref{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}\\%
        },
    solution/pre-body-hook = {%
        \label{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}%
        \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{Link to Question}\\
    },
    solution/post-body-hook = \newpage,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}
\begin{question}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{solution}

\newpage

\section{Answers}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Amusingly, if I use

```
solution/pre-body-hook = {%
    \begin{align}\label{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}
        1+1=2 
    \end{align}
}
```

then the question-->solution link works correctly. (Of course, I don't want a silly equation at the beginning of each solution.)

Comment: Have you seen [How to automatically links questions and solutions with the Exsheets package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222814/)

Comment: @clemens I have, it is linked in my question. That question currently only links Solutions --> Questions. It does not link Questions --> Solutions. My question is about implementing the suggestion you made in a comment.

Comment: Oh, alright (it's late on this side of the world :) ).

Comment: @clemens I was hoping you would see this, but didn't expect anything till (my) tomorrow =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions have no own counter so setting a `\label` is of no use. A `\label` *always* sets a reference to the last counter that's been stepped with `\refstepcounter`. That's why your example with the equation seems to work. But it doesn't: the label refers to the equation rather than the solution.

What you can do is add a `\hypertarget` and link to that with `\hyperlink`.

The corresponding question number is available as question property with the name `counter`. Something like `Link to Solution \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}` should give you the link text you want:

```
\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperlink{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{Link to Solution
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  },
  solution/pre-hook = {
    \hypertarget{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{}%
  } ,
  solution/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{Link to Question
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  }
}
```

A complete document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets} %Requires version 0.19
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperlink{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{Link to Solution
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  },
  solution/pre-hook = {
    \hypertarget{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{}%
  } ,
  solution/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{Link to Question
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}
\begin{question}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{solution}

\newpage

\section{Answers}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it also possible that you can click directly on the "question" or "solution" without needing the additional text?

Comment: @student currently unfortunately not...