# How to underline headings with exsheets?

Tags: exsheets

Recently I discovered `exsheets` for creating my worksheets and exercise booklets. I usually do not use bold fonts, but underline my headings.

I'm sure there is a simple way to underline headings with `exsheets` - but so far I couldn't solve it satisfactorily.

My two best approaches are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

% the underline-hack
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myheadings}{default}{
     runin = true ,
     number-post-code = \space,
     attach = {
        main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[l,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)},
     join = {
        title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt)},
     post-code = \rule{.125\linewidth}{.3pt}
    }

\begin{document}

\SetupExSheets{ 
    headings-format = \underline,
    headings        = runin }
\begin{question}
Some question ...
\end{question}

\SetupExSheets{ 
    headings-format = \normalfont,
    headings        = myheadings }
\begin{question}
Another question ...
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs to:

[image]

The first way leads to an ugly result, the second one of cause is a hack.

Is there a better way to get the headings underlined?

Comment: Imho there is no simple method and to draw a line like in your second solution is the way to go.

Comment: One perfect example why I never was completely satisfied with the way the layout is implemented in `exsheets`

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly I finally found a way to get my underlined headings - once again with a hack:

First I leave the proper title empty:

```
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myheadings2}{default}{
     runin = true ,
     number-post-code = \space,
    }
```

Then I use the `pre-body-hook` definitions to obtain my underlined headings as wanted:

```
\SetupExSheets{
    headings-format = \normalfont,
    question/pre-body-hook = \underline{Übung \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}} \space,
    solution/pre-body-hook = \underline{Lösung \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}} \space,
    headings        = myheadings2 
}
```

Even the solution isn't very beautiful, there is a nice side-effect: it is possible to combine it with the answer proposed in [exsheets: Link Solutions back to Questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276291/exsheets-link-solutions-back-to-questions). So now it is possible to click directely on the headings to jump from question to solution and vice versa (if I haven't overlooked something):

```
\SetupExSheets{
    question/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperlink{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{\underline{Question 
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}}\par
  },
  solution/pre-hook = {%
    \hypertarget{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{}%
  },
  solution/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{\underline{Solution 
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}}\par
  },
  headings = myheadings2 }
```

Comment: This is much easier with `exsheets`' successor [`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim)