# Re-calling/re-printing a theorem from an external document

Tags: theorems, ieeetran, xr

For a manuscript I need to include theorem proofs as supplementary material. So I mention the theorem in the main file and I need to re-print the theorem in the supplementary material with the same theorem number and then provide the proof.

For this purpose I define the theorem in the `main.tex` file as follows:

```
\begin{restatable}{thm}{firsttheorem}
\label{thm:first}
  Sample theorem. 
\end{restatable}

\begin{proof}
  Refer to supplementary material.
\end{proof}
```

Then in my supplementary material file `supp.tex` I use the `xr` package and refer to my main document as

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{../main}
```

But I am not able to refer to the theorem as such

```
\firsttheorem*
```

It gives the following error message

```
Undefined control sequence.
\myfirsttheorem
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` provides tools to save boxes for later reuse. This is an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333613/1952

Comment: Typo in the title: *external