# Is it possible to compile but not showing a part?

Tags: compiling

If I have a chunk of code which I'd like to hide when compiling, is there something like

> `\noshow{chunk of code}`

So this chunk of code is still compiled but just not showing in the PDF? I know I can comment this part but problem is if I edit my own commands, the commented codes are not compiled and checked.

Comment: I've linked one solution, but if you search here for *hide* there are plenty of others, depending on whether you want to keep the space occupied by that section.

Comment: `\setbox0\vbox{<your-code-here>}`

Comment: Another related question: [Hide content to show later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/hide-content-to-show-later/257455#257455)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the linked duplicate is not a duplicate as this doesn't compile the code but gobbles it. The OP of this question is asking for a solution which actually compiles, but shows no ouptut.

Comment: on level of files you can use combination `\includeonly{...}` and `\include{...}`, for only part of text: as far as i know, is not possible. own command should be in preamble and not hidden from compilation.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this could be to typeset the stuff inside a box which you
never print. This does however not work for any content. In the below example
floats are not allowed and throw an error.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
This shows up
\thesection% here it is 0
\setbox0\vbox{This is evaluated but never shows up, additional spaces
however might be a problem, which is why I put the \% at the end of the
lines. To show that it's evaluated, I run this: \stepcounter{section}}% no space here
\thesection% here it is 1
\end{document}
```

The following does also evaluate the contents, but only `\AtEndDocument`, so if
you need the contents to be evaluated where you put those, don't use this. The
advantage is, that anything should work here which doesn't produce an error.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{environ,atbegshi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\contents@DontShowMe{}
\newcommand\addto@DontShowMe[1]
  {%
    \xdef\contents@DontShowMe{\unexpanded\expandafter{\contents@DontShowMe#1}}%
  }

\NewEnviron{DontShowMe}[1][1]
  {%
    \ifnum#1=0
      \expandafter\BODY
    \else
      \expandafter\addto@DontShowMe\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \fi
  }
\AtEndDocument
  {%
    \clearpage
    \AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}%
    \contents@DontShowMe
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This shows up
\thesection% here it is 0
\begin{DontShowMe}
  This code doesn't show up and is evaluated at the end of the document. To show
  this: \stepcounter{section}
  \begin{figure}test\end{figure}
  To produce an error to check that it does evaluate uncomment this: %\PackageError{foo}{foo}{foo}
\end{DontShowMe}
\thesection% here it is still 0
\end{document}
```

**One environment to rule them all:**

You can use the optional argument to decide the point of evaluation. `0` means show, `1` means in a `\vbox` at this point (no floats usable), `2` means `\AtEndDocument` (and because the `\AtEndDocument` is added `\AtEndDocument`, it should be really late) floats should work here -- but captions don't make it to the `\listof...`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{environ,atbegshi}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifAtEnd@DontShowMe
\newcommand*\contents@DontShowMe{}
\newcommand\addto@DontShowMe[1]
  {%
    \xdef\contents@DontShowMe{\unexpanded\expandafter{\contents@DontShowMe#1}}%
  }

\NewEnviron{DontShowMe}[1][2]
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      \expandafter\BODY
    \or
      \setbox0\vbox{\BODY}%
    \or
      \global\AtEnd@DontShowMetrue
      \expandafter\addto@DontShowMe\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \fi
  }
\AtEndDocument
  {%
    \ifAtEnd@DontShowMe% only include this piece of code if it was used
      \AtEndDocument
        {%
          \clearpage
          \AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}%
          \contents@DontShowMe
        }%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
This shows up
\thesection% here it is 0
\begin{DontShowMe}
  This code doesn't show up and is evaluated at the end of the document.
  To show this: \stepcounter{section}
  \begin{figure}test\caption{test}\end{figure}
  To produce an error to check that it does evaluate uncomment this:
  %\PackageError{foo}{foo}{foo}
\end{DontShowMe}
\thesection% here it is still 0
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to know more: how long is the hidden text? Will you provide the PDF to others or only a printout? And so on.

For example, you could simply use white »coloured« text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
This is text.
\textcolor{white}{This text will not be printed. However, you can copy it out of
  the pdf.}

  \llap{\textcolor{white}{invisible text, can't be copied.}}{However, you can do
    funny things, but only without a linebreak.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I understood he wants to run custom commands even if those aren't used for debugging.

Comment: @Skillmon We do not know enough, let us wait until the OP provides more detailes.