# Hyperlinks from exercises to solutions and vice versa

Tags: hyperref, mdframed, exercises, answers

Writing lecture notes containing exercises and solutions, I would like to create hyperlinks from the exercises to their solutions and vice versa. I use the packages *mdframed*, *hyperref* and *answers* (and for some reasons I would like to stick at least with the first two). The example below almost does what I want. However, the hyperlink from an exercise to its solution is now the *name* ("Exercise") of the exercise, while I would like it to be its *number* ("1"). How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\Newassociation{sol}{answ}{ans}\Opensolutionfile{ans}

\mdtheorem{ex}{\hyperlink{ex:\theex}{Exercise}\hypertarget{sol:\theex}{}}
\renewenvironment{answ}[1]{{\hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{#1}}\quad}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
This is an exercise.
\begin{sol}
This is the solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\input{ans}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another proposal using `xsim` instead of `answers` but using your requirement `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{myex}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    frametitle={%
      \hypertarget{ex:\ExerciseID}{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}}
      \hyperlink{sol:\ExerciseID}{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    }]%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{mysol}{%
  \par\noindent
  \hyperlink
    {ex:\ExerciseID}
    {\hypertarget{sol:\ExerciseID}{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}}%
  \quad
}{\par}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = myex ,
  solution/template = mysol ,
  print-solutions/headings = false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  This is the solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
  This is another exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  This is the other solution.
\end{solution}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you later want to switch to `tcolorbox` instead it would only require changing the template definition `myex`:

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{myex}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, colback = white]
    \textbf{%
      \hypertarget{ex:\ExerciseID}{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}}
      \hyperlink{sol:\ExerciseID}{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    }\par\smallskip
}{\end{tcolorbox}}
```

It would also be possible to define the environments `ex` and `sol` if you'd insist on these names:

Load the package with the `blank` option, it now does not define `exercise` and `solution`

```
\usepackage[blank]{xsim}
```

and define `ex` and `sol`:

```
\DeclareExerciseType {exercise} {
  exercise-env      = ex ,
  solution-env      = sol ,
  exercise-name     = \XSIMtranslate {exercise} ,
  exercises-name    = \XSIMtranslate {exercises} ,
  solution-name     = \XSIMtranslate {solution} ,
  solutions-name    = \XSIMtranslate {solutions} ,
  exercise-template = myex ,
  solution-template = mysol
}
```

As option setup now only `\xsimsetup{print-solutions/headings = false}` is needed in the above example and the environmants can be changed:

```
\begin{ex}
  This is an exercise.
\end{ex}
\begin{sol}
  This is the solution.
\end{sol}
\begin{ex}
  This is another exercise.
\end{ex}
\begin{sol}
  This is the other solution.
\end{sol}
```

Comment: Dear @cgnieder, thanks for your answer (and also thanks for your package!). The cluttering of my folder is maybe not optimal, but a brief look at the xsim documentation shows that there seems to be a way around this. I will have to spend some time and get to know your package.

Comment: @Fred it's easy: `\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}`

Comment: Dear @cgnieder, thanks for all the additional information and the update. It is hard to choose, but I will reward your answer with the bounty. It seems to me to be the clearest way to get what I want (but this has maybe more to do with my limited understanding of LaTeX).

Answer (score 5):

Although you want to stick to `mdframed` I propose a solution with `tcolorbox` because it can provide `mdframed+answer` behaviour. This solution also uses `hyperref` for links.

Like `answers`, `tcolorbox` offers some commands and environments to define boxes with parts which will be saved on an external file and printed later on.

Following code is a simplification of example in [section 8.3 from `tcolorbox` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=135) (something similar can be seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257455/1952))

Every `ex` box will save the solution (text after `\tcblower`) into an independent file.

Command `\tcbstartrecording[file1]` will start to save into `file1` the name of all exercises to be included into the solutions list.

Command `\tcbstoprecording` does what it says.

Command `\tcbinputrecords[file1]` loads all solutions and print them.

About references, I've suposed that every exercise contains a solution and they respective names are references to their solution/exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{ex}{+O{}}{%
        enhanced, colframe=black, colback=white, sharp corners, 
        attach title to upper=\par, coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Exercise~\ref{solution@\thetcbcounter}},
        label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
        lowerbox=ignored,
        savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
        record={\string\solution{\thetcbcounter}%
               {solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
        #1}

\NewTotalTColorBox[auto counter]{\solution}{mm}{%
        enhanced, blanker,             
        coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={\ref{exercise@\thetcbcounter}},
        label={solution@\thetcbcounter},
        attach title to upper={\ },
        }{\input{#2}}

\begin{document}

% We start to record all `tcblower` parts in file `file1` for later processing 
\tcbstartrecording[file1]

%Every exercise box contains an upper part which is processed and
%printed and a lower (solution) which printing is delayed.
%
\begin{ex}
This is an exercise.
\tcblower
This is the solution for first exercise
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
This is an exercise.
\tcblower
This is the solution for second exercise
\end{ex}

\tcbstoprecording

%previous recorded files with solutions are processed and printed
\tcbinputrecords[file1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tcolorbox` is great :)

Comment: Dear @Ignasi, thanks for your answer. It solves my problem. Of course, the downside is that I have to learn how to use tcolorbox to get what I did up to now with mdframed, but maybe that is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @Ignasi: There is a small problem. If I set a label to an ex-environment and refer to it with \ref, this does not work anymore (i.e., results in questions marks). Do you know why?

Comment: @FredRohrer If you look at the code, every `ex` and `sol` declare its own `label` which are `exercise@\thetcbcounter` and `solution@\thetcbcounter`, you can use them or change it according your convenience.

Comment: @FredRohrer About changing from `mdframed` to `tcolorbox` should be not too difficult. You already know where to find help ;-)

Comment: Ah, now I understand the issue with the label. But it seems to be not stable, i.e., a reference to Exercise 1 is \ref{exercise@1} (needs me to look up the number) and has to be changed if I insert an exercise before Exercise 1.

Comment: @FredRohrer Please look at updated code. Now every `ex` has a mandatory parameter which is the label. `\begin{ex}{first}` -> \ref{first}. My test worked, but I don't know in your work case.

Comment: Dear @Ignasi, thanks again for your answer and the additional information. It was not easy for me to choose who gets the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `\theex` at the beginning of the `mdtheorem`, using `startcode` option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\Newassociation{sol}{answ}{ans}\Opensolutionfile{ans}

\mdtheorem[startcode={\let\theexold\theex\renewcommand{\theex}{\hyperlink{ex:\theexold}{\theexold}\hypertarget{sol:\theexold}{}}}]{ex}{Exercise}
\renewenvironment{answ}[1]{{\hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{#1}}\quad}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{ex}
        This is an exercise.
        \begin{sol}
            This is the solution.
        \end{sol}
    \end{ex}
    
    \begin{ex}
        This is an exercise.
        \begin{sol}
            This is the solution.
        \end{sol}
    \end{ex}
    \Closesolutionfile{ans}
    \input{ans}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @NBur, thanks a lot! This seems to do what I want. I have to wait to award the bounty, but I will wait anyway some time to see whether there are other suggestions. (But it seems to be hard to find one that is more elegant.)

Comment: Maybe there is a more elegant solution: I'm a bit disappointed having to redefine `\theex` each time the environment is called.

Comment: Dear @NBur, thanks again for your answer. It was not easy for me to choose who gets the bounty.